# How to get a Visual Studio Macro Value into a pre processor directive?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

Within my projects I need to access the value of the `$(SolutionDir)` macro at runtime. To do that I've tried adding pre processor entries like `DEBUG_ROOT=$(SolutionDir)` or `DEBUG_ROOT=\"$(SolutionDir)\"` but this results in various compiler errors due to invalid escape sequences since `$(SolutionDir)` contains single `\` characters (e.g. `$(SolutionDir) = c:\users\lukas\desktop\sandbox\`).

Is there an easy way to pass the value of the `$(SolutionDir)` macro into my code?

### Backround

I am utilizing function `OutputDebugString(..)` quite a lot within my debug builds to see what my code is doing.

```
/* debug.h */
#define STRINGIFY(x) #x
#define TOSTRING(x) STRINGIFY(x)
#define LOCATION __FILE__ "(" TOSTRING(__LINE__) ") : "

#if !defined(DEBUG_ROOT)
#define DEBUG_ROOT    "#"   /* escape string to force strstr(..) to fail */
#endif

/*
**  DBGMSG macro setting up and writing a debug string.
**  Note: copying the strings together is faster than calling OutputDebugString(..) several times!
**  Todo: Ensure that size of dbgStr is not exceeded!!!
*/
#define DBGMSG(text) \
    { \
        char dbgStr[1024]; \
        char *pFile; \
        pFile = strstr(LOCATION, DEBUG_ROOT); \
        if (pFile == LOCATION) \
        { \
            wsprintf(dbgStr, ".%s", pFile + strlen(DEBUG_ROOT)); \
        } \
        else \
        { \
            wsprintf(dbgStr, "%s", LOCATION); \
        } \
        wsprintf(dbgStr, "%s%s", dbgStr, text); \
        OutputDebugString(dbgStr); \
    }


/* somewhere in the code */
DBGMSG("test")
```

Using the snipped will cause a printout like `c:\users\lukas\desktop\sandbox\testconsole\main.c(17) : test` within the output window of Visual Studio. This speeds up finding the location within your code that caused the printout since you can simply double click on the line of the output window and Visual Studio automatically jumps to the specified code location.

Since depending on the location of the solution the absolute path (`__FILE__` expands to the absolute path) the "header" of the debug strings may get quite long. I've seen that Visual Studio is smart enough to understand relative paths to e.g. the solution root directory. To reduce the length of the strings I'm checking if `__FILE__` is within a `DEBUG_ROOT` directory and if so I'm replacing `DEBUG_ROOT` with a simple `'.'` to generate a relative path to `DEBUG_ROOT`. So if I write `#define DEBUG_ROOT  "c:\\users\\lukas\\desktop\\sandbox"` the final debug string of the example above will be `.\testconsole\main.c(17) : test`. Currently I'm setting the value of `DEBUG_ROOT` within the preprocessor definitions of the project.

Since several people are working on the project it is not a smart move to have an absolute path within the project settings since each team member may check-out the source files to a different root directory. So I've tried to use the `$(SolutionDir)` macro to create something like `DEBUG_ROOT=\"$(SolutionDir)\\"`. But by doing so I'm running into trouble. Since `$(SolutionDir) = c:\users\lukas\desktop\sandbox\` expanding of `DEBUG_ROOT` leads to undefined escape sequences, unterminated strings and a lot more ugly compiler errors...

### Solution

Based on the answer of [***kfsone***](https://stackoverflow.com/users/257645/kfsone) I've come up with the following solution which makes it possible to pass any value of a Visual Studio macro such as `$(SolutionDir)` into your code. The following solution is independent of the used Visual Studio version and language C/C++.

Adding `SOLUTION_DIR=\"$(SolutionDir)"` to the preprocessor entries of your project results in a compiler command line which looks something like that:

```
/Od /D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "SOLUTION_DIR=\"C:\Users\Lukas\Desktop\sandbox\""
/Gm /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /Fo"Debug\\" /Fd"Debug\vc80.pdb" /W3 /nologo /c /Wp64 /ZI /TP
/errorReport:prompt
```

Note that `$(SolutionDir)` is preceeded by a `\"` to create a `"` characted infront of the value of `$(SolutionDir)` but is terminated by a single `"`. Looking at the compiler's command line shows that the terminating `"` is escaped by the last `\` of `$(SolutionDir)`.

Using `SOLUTION_DIR` within your code results in unknown escape sequences and the string ends up with all `\` characters being removed. This is done by the compiler which expands `SOLUTION_DIR` and intepretes `\` as begin of an escape sequence.

Using the `TOSTRING(x)` macro of my code posted above solves this issue since it forces the compiler to use the string as it is without further processing.

```
#define STRINGIFY(x) #x
#define TOSTRING(x) STRINGIFY(x)

#define SOLUTION_DIR2   TOSTRING(SOLUTION_DIR)

// the following line may cause compiler warnings (unrecognized character escape sequence)
printf("%s\n", SOLUTION_DIR);    // prints C:UsersLukasDesktopsandbox 

// the following line compiles without any warnings
printf("%s\n", SOLUTION_DIR2);   // prints "C:\Users\Lukas\Desktop\sandbox"
```

From here it is only a simple step to do some string magic to remove the `"` characters from `SOLUTION_DIR2`.

Comment: From your question it appears that you are able to use `$SolutionDir` in C++ but are only facing problems with the backslashes. Is this the case? If so how did you do it (I'm not able to figure it out). Also what version of VS are you using?

Comment: Hmm, no, it is not $(SolutionDir).  Your main.c is stored in the project directory.  Won't work for code in library projects of course.  You need to trim the path at runtime, you get the project directory handed on a silver platter through argv[0] and GetCurrentDirectory().

Comment: @Motti: I cannot use `$(SolutionDir)` within my code directly. Therefore I've used the workaround to pass `$(SolutionDir)` into my code by defining a pre processor direvtive `DEBUG_ROOT=\"$(SolutionDir)\\"` within the project settings of Visual Studio. But obviously I'm getting invalid escape sequences since Visual Studio uses `'\'` instead of `'/'`.

Comment: Seems like you just need to properly escape DEBUG_ROOT once on startup or perhaps the first time the log function is called and use that variable instead.

Comment: @HansPassant: I've posted my entire code which trims the paths at runtime. You're right I've made a copy/paste error with the paths which I've also fixed. Using `argv[0]` and `GetCurrentDirectory()` would introduce some sort of initialization which also has the drawback that Visual Studio will not find the files of nested libraries. That's why I'm using the solution directory as `DEBUG_ROOT` which will ensure that all debug messages are trimmed correctly. So I'm looking for a way to pass the solution directory into my code but I fear that using the `$(SolutionDir)` macro will not work.

Comment: @RetiredNinja: Good idea! I've tried the following: `char *debugRoot = DEBUG_ROOT;` and looked at the contents with the debugger. It seems that Visual Studio already escapes the value of `$(SolutionDir)` when compiling because all '\\' characters are gone and there is no way of restoring it :(

Comment: Lukas - I would suggest you condense this down to simply saying 'I wish to expose the $(SolutionDir) property within my project, such that `std::cout << SOLUTIONDIR << "\n";` generates the correct output.The problem being that when I add `SOLUTIONDIR=$(SolutionDir)` or `SOLUTIONDIR=\"$(SolutionDir)\"` the directory separators in $(SolutionDIr) are treated as escapes and vanish.

This compact version will eliminate confusion and probably make it easier to get an answer to this interesting question.

Comment: @kfsone: Thanks for this suggestion! Sometimes it needs someone who looks at a problem who is not burried by it ;-) I've updated my original question.

Comment: Thanks for the STRINGIFY macro!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a C++11 feature, raw string literals, available in Visual Studio version 2013 and above, which lets you do this. The syntax is

```
'R"' <delimiter> '(' <string> ')' <delimiter> '"'
```

e.g. if you choose "?:?" as your delimiter

```
R"?:?(don't\escape)?:?"
```

or if you choose "Foo123"

```
R"Foo123(don't\escape)Foo123"
```

But for this demonstration, I'm going with ? as a single-character delimiter, because we know it's illegal in Windows filenames.

Now you can set the project-level Preprocessor Definition:

```
DIR=R"?(C:\\Temp\\)?"
```

and then the following code generates the expected output

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << DIR << '\n';
}
```

writes

```
C:\\Temp\\
```

instead of

```
C:\Temp\
```

Now to capture the SolutionDir macro it's as simple as

```
DIR=R"?($(SolutionDir))?"
```

If this is a pain, you can add a custom macro in a Property Sheet. Go to "Property Explorer" and right click your project, add a new property sheet, call it "ProjectMacros.props" or something.

Expand your project and select one of the configurations, e.g. debug, double click the "PropertySheet" value to open "PropertySheet PropertyPages" and select "UserMacros"

[image: The PropertySheet macros page]

Click "Add Macro"

```
Name: RawSolutionDir
Value: R"?path?($(SolutionDir))?path?"
```

You should now be able to use the preprocessor entry

```
SOLUTIONDIR=$(RawSolutionDir)
```

Comment: Very interresting info about a feature I wasn't aware of until now! I've tried your solution and it works perfectly for Visual Studio 2013 and C++. Unfortunately I have a lot of C code as well which results in `SOLUTIONDIR = "?"`. But your suggestion has given me some ideas ... if they work I'll share them here.

Comment: I've accepted your answer since it is a working solution and helped me to create a solution which does not rely on the Visual Studio version and C++ language. Thanks for your help!