# Use environment var in source code ( Compiling time )

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, environment-variables, preprocessor

How can I use an environment variable, say %WINDIR% in VS? I tried in Properties > Preprocessor > Definitions > I added: `ENV_VAR="($Windir)"`

in my .cpp:
`std::string s = ENV_VAR`

but when executed it prints:

`C:windows`

How do I fix this?

Comment: do you mean char `*ptr = getenv ("YourEnviroVar");`

Comment: @MahmoudMubarak No I want to do this in compiling time

Comment: When you add it to the Preprocessor settings, this means the environment variable is evaluated at compile time, opposed to using `getenv`, which will get the variable value at runtime, i.e. on the target machine. Which of both do you want?

Comment: using `$(EnvVar)` in the project settings should work fine, as far as I know you can use environment variables in the project settings the same as project variables, like $(OutDir)

Comment: @KarstenKoop If I use just $(EnvVar), without quotes, the code doesn't even compile... BTW, I want it this in compiling time, edited the title.

Comment: Without quotes, you'd have to stringify the preprocessor variable. But your problem is probably the single backslash that's put in the string by the preprocessor, while you need escaped backslashes for a C-string

Comment: found something [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3e57b146-9353-44e5-a6a8-fa0ebb7d7f96/converting-preprocessor-definition-into-string?forum=vcgeneral)

Comment: Of course embedding your compilation machine's %WINDIR% in the executable is exactly the wrong thing to do, but whatever...

Comment: @n.m. it's just an example

Comment: @KarstenKoop from what I read is that it will create a .h file containing the string. is this not possible without creating any header?

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution:

[How to get a Visual Studio Macro Value into a pre processor directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30438911/how-to-get-a-visual-studio-macro-value-into-a-pre-processor-directive)

in my example I should add:
`ENV_VAR=R"?($(WINDIR))?"`